# Generate IL using Mono.Cecil for several types

Tags: c#, mono

I have several script text files which contain one or more types. These scripts are big files which may contain 10.000 lines each. I parse them and now I want to use Cecil to generate IL. My question is: How can I generate IL for several files and then .Write("myExeFile") I couldn't find how to work with Cecil when we deal with a big amount of code and types. Is there a way to generate a IL file for each script file without write the EXE/DLL and then extract the IL. I am trying to avoid memory leak and high use of memory and also bad performance.